# Value of type 'CAPPlugin' has no member 'getConfig'

Tags: javascript, xcode, ionic-framework, types, capacitor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTsPK.jpg)

I am using ionic v 6 and capacitor version 3 and when trying to build ios code getting this error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You are using @capacitor/push-notifications 4.x version while still using @capacitor/ios 3.x.

Version 4.x of the plugins are meant to be used with version 4.x of platforms.

You should update @capacitor/ios to 4.x or downgrade @capacitor/push-notifications to 1.x.

Note, if you decide to upgrade to 4.x, you should also update android, cli and core packages and since it's a major version it requires some other changes, check the [migration guide](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/4-0)